# How to run shell script in R and get the output into table?

Tags: r, shell

I know to run a shell script in **R** is using system command:

```
my.table <- system(command,intern=TRUE)
```

However, if the result of my "command" is to print out a table, and I want R to read the table directly into its own data structure. (something like data frame) Is there an easy way to do that? Because the current output in "table" is a character string table. What I want is the **R** object as read.table().

Comment: I suspect you'll have to do some text parsing yourself.  A few unsolicited suggestions: 1) The `->` assignment is technically correct, but to be avoided.  2) Please post reproducible questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as you'll get better answers.  In this case, you'll definitely want to post some sample output.

Comment: "The -> assignment is technically correct, but to be avoided" What?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the result 'table' has white-space separators and carriage-returns to mark lines, then you should pass the results to the 'text' argument of read.table:

```
 inp.tbl <- read.table(text = system(command,intern=TRUE) )
```

Comment: (A caveat for users of earlier versions of R: The 'text' argument to `read.table` and derivatives thereof is a relatively recent addition.)

Answer (score 4):

I expect using `pipe` will be more efficient in memory and time than `system` with `intern`

```
inp.tbl <- read.table(pipe(command) )
```