# Read data into R deleting or skipping lines containing characters

Tags: r

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm not coming across an answer. I would like to import a data frame into R without processing the lines in a text editor first. Essentially, I want R to do it on read in. So all lines containing

```
FRAME   1 of ***
OR
ATOM-WISE TOTAL CONTACT ENERGY
```

will be skipped, deleted or ignored.

And all that will be left is;

```
Chain Resnum    Atom number Energy(kcal/mol)
ATOM      C     500   1519          -2.1286
ATOM      C     500   1520          -1.1334
ATOM      C     500   1521          -0.8180
ATOM      C     500   1522          -0.7727
```

Is there a simple solution to this? I'm not sure which `scan()` of `read.table()` arguments would work.

**EDIT**

I was able to use `readLines` and `gsub` to read in the file and remove the (un)necessary lines. I omitted the "" left from the deleted words and now I am trying to convert the character df to a regular(numeric) df. When I use `data.frame(x)` or `as.data.frame(x)` I am left with a data frame with 100K rows and only one variable. There should be at least 5 variables.

Comment: Is it a speed issue? i.e. Why couldn't you delete these lines after import?

Comment: The text makes the data harder to work with. Deleting these lines would give me a numeric data frame which is what I want.

Comment: Can you give a bigger example of your file with the data and non-data lines?

Comment: Use `readLines`, then `grepl` to exclude rows that match unwanted list of strings. Or you can run system command for `read.table`, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690867/how-to-run-shell-script-in-r-and-get-the-output-into-table)

Comment: You can also convert to numeric once you delete those lines (`as.numeric`)

Comment: can you go into more detail about readLines and grepl?

Comment: @D.A.Ragland this post is what you want, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261776/extracting-data-from-text-files it is even related to Molecular Modelling (but GAMESS (US)).

Comment: This post isn't what I was going for, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`readLines` gives you a vector with one character string for each line of the file.  So you have to split these strings into the elements you want before you convert to a dataframe.  If you have nice space-separated values, try:

```
m = matrix(unlist(strsplit(data, " +")), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
    # where 'data' is the name of the vector of strings
df = data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then for each column with numeric data, use `as.numeric()` on the column to convert.